# Query to get parent records with child record, followed by next parent-child records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in the following format in the `Names` table in database:

```
ID  | Name                     | ParentID
1   | Parent 1                 | 0
2   | Parent 2                 | 0
3   | Parent 1 Child 1         | 1
4   | Parent 2 Child 1         | 2
5   | Parent 1 Child 1 Child   | 3
6   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1 | 4
7   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2 | 4
```

The `ParentID` column is having data from `ID` column as parent record. `ParentID` with `0` value indicates root items. I need to write a query to get data in the following order:

```
ID  | Name                     | ParentID
1   | Parent 1                 | 0
3   | Parent 1 Child 1         | 1
5   | Parent 1 Child 1 Child   | 3
2   | Parent 2                 | 0
4   | Parent 2 Child 1         | 2    
6   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1 | 4
7   | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2 | 4
```

I need to get the root record(record with `ParentID` as 0) followed by all the `child` and `sub-children` of this root record and then get the next root record followed by `child` and `sub-children` of the this root record and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I propose here uses the concept of materialized path. The following is an example of materialized paths using your sample data. I hope it helps you to understand materialized path concept:

```
+----+--------------------------+----------+------------------+
| ID |           Name           | ParentID | MaterializedPath |
+----+--------------------------+----------+------------------+
|  1 | Parent 1                 |        0 | 1                |
|  2 | Parent 2                 |        0 | 2                |
|  4 | Parent 2 Child 1         |        2 | 2.4              |
|  6 | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1 |        4 | 2.4.6            |
|  7 | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2 |        4 | 2.4.7            |
|  3 | Parent 1 Child 1         |        1 | 1.3              |
|  5 | Parent 1 Child 1 Child   |        3 | 1.3.5            |
+----+--------------------------+----------+------------------+
```

Each node `N` has a materialized path, this path tells you the way to go from the root node to the node `N`. It can be build concatenating the node id's. For example, to reach node `5` starting from its root node, you visit node `1`, node `3`, and node `5`, so node `5` materialized path is `1.3.5`

Coincidentally, the order you are looking for can be achieved ordering by the materialized path.

On the previous example, materialized paths are buit concatenating strings, but I prefer binary concatenation for a number of reasons.

To build the materialized paths you need the following recursive CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE Tree
(
    ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Tree PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name nvarchar(250) NOT NULL,
    ParentID int NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Tree(ID, Name, ParentID) VALUES
(1, 'Parent 1', 0),
(2, 'Parent 2', 0),
(3, 'Parent 1 Child 1', 1),
(4, 'Parent 2 Child 1', 2),
(5, 'Parent 1 Child 1 Child', 3),
(6, 'Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1', 4),
(7, 'Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2', 4)

GO
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        N.ID, N.Name, N.ParentID, CAST(N.ID AS varbinary(512)) AS MaterializedPath
    FROM
        Tree N
    WHERE
        N.ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        N.ID, N.Name, N.ParentID, CAST( T.MaterializedPath + CAST(N.ID AS binary(4)) AS varbinary(512) ) AS MaterializedPath
    FROM
        Tree N INNER JOIN T
            ON N.ParentID = T.ID

)
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY T.MaterializedPath
```

Result:

```
+----+--------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
| ID |           Name           | ParentID |      MaterializedPath      |
+----+--------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
|  1 | Parent 1                 |        0 | 0x00000001                 |
|  3 | Parent 1 Child 1         |        1 | 0x0000000100000003         |
|  5 | Parent 1 Child 1 Child   |        3 | 0x000000010000000300000005 |
|  2 | Parent 2                 |        0 | 0x00000002                 |
|  4 | Parent 2 Child 1         |        2 | 0x0000000200000004         |
|  6 | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 1 |        4 | 0x000000020000000400000006 |
|  7 | Parent 2 Child 1 Child 2 |        4 | 0x000000020000000400000007 |
+----+--------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
```

The above recursive CTE starts with the root nodes. Calculating the materialized path for a root node is trivially straightforward, it's the ID of the node itself. On the next iteration the CTE joins root nodes with its child nodes. The materialized path for a child node `CN` is the concatenation of the materialized path of its parent node `PN` and the id of node `CN`. Subsequent iterations advance one level down on the tree until the leaf nodes are reached.