# Display child rows under parent rows in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

There is a table that has information about projects stored in it. Each Project has an ID Column(FPNNumber) and a Parent ID column. If the project has a parent project, the user selects the ID number of the parent project to go in the parent project cell for that row. If it doesn't have a parent project, the parent project column will have a 0. I've seen some questions on here similar to mine but it looks like they are all using a level column which I don't have or want to use in my query.

My stored for getting the data from the database looks like this:

```
SELECT h.[Priority]
  ,h.[FPNNumber]
  ,h.[ProjectName]
  ,sp.SponsorName
  ,pm.ProjectManagerName
  ,o.[OrgName]
  ,HealthID
  ,[StrategicAlignmentID] + [FinancialAlignmentID] + [TechnologyAlignmentID] As ProjectScore
  ,h.[Cost]
  ,h.[Budget]
  ,h.[PercentComplete]
  ,Convert(varchar(10),h.[EstimatedImpDt], 101) As EstimatedImpDt
  ,[EstimatedROI]
  ,h.[ExpectedBenefit]
  ,CONVERT(Decimal(10, 2),((DATEDIFF(day, h.[PaybackPerioddt], GETDATE()))/365.0)) As PaybackPerioddt

FROM [ProjectNew].[Header] h
   join ProjectNew.Sponsor sp ON h.SponsorID = sp.SponsorID
   join ProjectNew.ProjectManager pm ON h.ProjectManagerID = pm.ProjectManagerID
   Join ProjectNew.Organization o ON h.OrgID = o.OrgID
   where StatusID is null or StatusID < 12
```

One thing I've tried and worked partially but doesn't work quite how I need was

```
;WITH Parents
AS(
   SELECT h.[Priority]
  ,h.[FPNNumber]
  ,h.[ProjectName]
  ,sp.SponsorName
  ,pm.ProjectManagerName
  ,o.[OrgName]
  ,HealthID
  ,[StrategicAlignmentID] + [FinancialAlignmentID] + [TechnologyAlignmentID] As ProjectScore
  ,h.[Cost]
  ,h.[Budget]
  ,h.[PercentComplete]
  ,Convert(varchar(10),h.[EstimatedImpDt], 101) As EstimatedImpDt
  ,[EstimatedROI]
  ,h.[ExpectedBenefit]
  ,CONVERT(Decimal(10, 2),((DATEDIFF(day, h.[PaybackPerioddt], GETDATE()))/365.0)) As PaybackPerioddt

FROM [FPN].[ProjectNew].[Header] h
  join ProjectNew.Sponsor sp ON h.SponsorID = sp.SponsorID
  join ProjectNew.ProjectManager pm ON h.ProjectManagerID = pm.ProjectManagerID
  Join ProjectNew.Organization o ON h.OrgID = o.OrgID
  WHERE StatusID is null or StatusID < 12 and h.ParentID = 0
Union All
  SELECT he.[Priority]
  ,he.[FPNNumber]
  ,he.[ProjectName]
  ,sp.SponsorName
  ,pm.ProjectManagerName
  ,o.[OrgName]
  ,he.HealthID
  ,[StrategicAlignmentID] + [FinancialAlignmentID] + [TechnologyAlignmentID] As ProjectScore
  ,he.[Cost]
  ,he.[Budget]
  ,he.[PercentComplete]
  ,Convert(varchar(10),he.[EstimatedImpDt], 101) As EstimatedImpDt
  ,he.[EstimatedROI]
  ,he.[ExpectedBenefit]
  ,CONVERT(Decimal(10, 2),((DATEDIFF(day, he.[PaybackPerioddt], GETDATE()))/365.0)) As PaybackPerioddt

FROM [FPN].[ProjectNew].[Header] he
  join ProjectNew.Sponsor sp ON he.SponsorID = sp.SponsorID
  join ProjectNew.ProjectManager pm ON he.ProjectManagerID = pm.ProjectManagerID
  Join ProjectNew.Organization o ON he.OrgID = o.OrgID
  Join Parents cte on cte.FPNNumber = he.ParentID
WHERE StatusID is null or StatusID < 12
)
Select * from Parents
```

When I execute that, the results look like this:

```
 ID | ParentID
----------------
 1  | 0
 2  | 0
 4  | 2
 5  | 2
 3  | 1
 6  | 1
 7  | 1
```

I need it to look like this:

```
 ID | ParentID
----------------
 1  | 0
 3  | 1
 6  | 1
 7  | 1
 2  | 0
 4  | 2
 5  | 2
```

So for the row with ID 2 has the two corresponding child projects under it, but the Child Projects of ID 1 are below that.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get all child projects to display under their parent project? If so, Is there a way to do this, and then when I call that data to the ListView in Visual Studio, have it so if the user clicks a sort button, it doesn't scramble up the child projects?

Comment: Please show expected data

Comment: Just looking at your result not your code yet it appears that you just need an order by on your select from the recursive cte that is a typical result but you need to order it after

Comment: @TheGameiswar I added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select * from Parents
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ParentId = 0 THEN Id ELSE ParentId END
    ,ID
```

Interestingly this question still seems to be getting some attention so I will expand on my narrative a little to make it clearer what is happening during recursion.

your anchor table starts out and grabs 2 rows it holds those in memory and then each of those 2 rows are joined to their child rows then in the next iteration those children are then joined to their children.  So it traverses the all of the lineages simultaneously not one at a time which is why you get the order which shows that.  Level 0 First Then Level 1, 2, etc.

So if you desire results in a particular order such as parent then children you must tell sql to order them with an order by statement.  In your particular case because of the way you identified and continued your ParentIds during recursion you need to make the Parentless Parent (0) equal to itself and then order by ids.  This can be done in a case expression as shows above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it seems that you want to make sure the hierarchy is in the proper order.

The following is a generic sample use uses a Sequence based on Title in this case, but can be any available field.

Also, the Range Keys are completely optional. (remove cteR1 and cteR2 if not needed)

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Pt int,Title varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values (0,null,'Tags'),(1,0,'Transportation'),(2,1,'Boats'),(3,1,'Cars'),(4,1,'Planes'),(5,1,'Trains'),(6,0,'Technology'),(7,6,'FTP'),(8,6,'HTTP'),(9,0,'Finance'),(10,9,'FTP'),(11,9,'401K'),(12,2,'Sail'),(13,2,'Powered'),(14,6,'Internet'),(15,6,'Database'),(16,15,'SQL Server'),(17,15,'MySQL'),(18,15,'MS Access')

Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 9
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by Title) as varchar(500))
           ,ID
           ,Pt
           ,Lvl=1
           ,Title 
     From   @Table 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(Pt,-1) else ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.Title)) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.ID
           ,cteCD.Pt,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.Title 
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.Pt = cteHB.ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Title
      ,A.Seq   -- < Included for Illustration
 From cteHB A
 Join cteR1 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join cteR2 C on A.ID=C.ID
 Order By B.R1
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try something similar to the solution provided in the below stack overflow question:

[Query to get parent records with child record, followed by next parent-child records in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979233/query-to-get-parent-records-with-child-record-followed-by-next-parent-child-rec#28982306)

or you can try the below solution.

I have provided my solution below to get the order you want. I have used *rnk* as additional column, which you can ignore in the final result set.

```
CREATE TABLE #ParentChild (
    projectId INT
    ,parentProjectId INT
    )

INSERT INTO #ParentChild
VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,2),(7,2),(8,2);

SELECT projectid
    ,parentprojectid
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY parentconsider ORDER BY projectid
        ) AS rnk
FROM (
    SELECT projectId
        ,parentProjectId
        ,CASE 
            WHEN parentProjectId = 0
                THEN projectId
            ELSE parentProjectId
            END AS parentconsider
    FROM #ParentChild
    ) AS x
```

Comment: Added my implementation for more clarity