# Recursive query in mysql_

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a hierarchy of organizations in organization_table.
In this table I've data like,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
organization_id | organisation_type | organization_parent_id |    
--------------------------------------------------------------  Sample
101             |   Primary         | 101                    |   101
102             |   Secondary       | 101                    |    |
103             |   Secondary       | 102                    |   102
104             |   Primary         | 104                    |    |
105             |   Secondary       | 104                    |   103
106             |   Secondary       | 105                    |
```

Here 101 is a primary parent for 101,102 and 103 same as 104 is primary parent for 104, 105 and 106.
So by query I need to find Primary parent for record_id 103 and 106.

I'm weak at recursive query execution so please help me out to a suitable way with this.

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to get parent records with child record, followed by next parent-child records in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979233/query-to-get-parent-records-with-child-record-followed-by-next-parent-child-rec)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the recursive CTE looks like:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select organization_id, organization_parent_id, 1 as lev
      from organization_table ot
      where organization_id in (103, 106)
      union all
      select cte.organization_id, ot.organization_parent_id, lev + 1
      from cte join
           organization_table ot
           on ot.organization_id = cte.organization_parent_id
      where organization_id in (103, 106)
    )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by organization_id order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT organization_id, organization_parent_id
         FROM organization_table
         WHERE organization_id IN (103, 106)
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ot.organization_id, ot.organization_parent_id
         FROM cte
         JOIN organization_table ot ON ot.organization_id = cte.organization_parent_id
         WHERE cte.organization_id != cte.organization_parent_id
       )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE organization_id = organization_parent_id;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hbEohJD9idtTq9WnDzVxg8/0)